# Parse byte array in client model of entity received from ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, asp.net-core

I've created a SomeFile class:

**C#:**

```
public class SomeFile
{
    public byte[] Content { get; set; }

    public string MimeType { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and this file is  returned in a such way:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetFiles(string guid)
{            
    return Ok(new SomeFile() { Content = zippedFiles.ToArray(), 
                   Name = $"zippedFiles.zip", MimeType = "application/x-zip-compressed" });
}
```

At **Angular side I've created model file**:

**Angular:**

```
export interface SomeFile {    
    Content: **Uint8Array** //am I correct to use this type?
    MimeType: string
    Name: string
}
```

and http service gets this object like this:

```
public downloadZip(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http 
        .get(fooUrl)
        .map((response: Response) => <SomeFile> response.json());  
};
```

What type should I use for **Content property at Angular side**?
Am I correct to use `Uint8Array`? 
Cause I get the error:

> ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected token P in JSON at position 0

May be I should not do `.map((response: Response) => <SomeFile> response.json());`?

Comment: You can't return binary data in json. You must encode it in base64 before you put it into JSON.

Comment: @Tseng do you mean? `System.Convert.ToBase64String(image)`

Comment: @Tseng and what type should I use for `Content` property at Angular side?

Comment: Yes and you have to treat it as string (both server and client sided)

Comment: @Tseng please, make a reply and I'll mark it as asnwer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON Format can't treat binary files, so you need to encode the binary information into base64 string and then return it.

As a result, you have to change the type from `byte[]` to `string`.